# Nested document references in firebase cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function in which I want to get data from a `firestore` collection `drivers`. But to get to a specific `driver` I need the `vehicle` code from `student` collection. Data from student collection is being retrieved successfully but not from the driver's collection. Why? please help

```
getDriverLoc() {
  //print('here');
  DocumentReference studentReference = Firestore.instance.collection("students").document(_userId);

studentReference.get().then((datasnapshot) {
  if (datasnapshot.exists) {
    print(datasnapshot.data['vehicle_code'].toString());
    String temp = datasnapshot.data['vehicle_code'].toString();

    DocumentReference driverReference = Firestore.instance.collection("drivers").document(temp);
    driverReference.get().then((datasnapshot2) {
      if (datasnapshot2.exists) {
        print("here");
        print(datasnapshot2.data['first_name'].toString());
        _currentCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(datasnapshot2.data['latitue'], datasnapshot2.data['longitude']),
            zoom: 16
        );
        final GoogleMapController controller = _controller.future as GoogleMapController;
        controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_currentCameraPosition));
      }
      else{
        print("No scene");
      }
    });

  }
  else {
    print("No such user");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: You need to `await` , and make the function async.

Comment: await on both instance request? @meditat

Comment: No, `then` will do the work in the second instance.